How to resolve "Function recursion limit exceeded" error in an AHK script running for extended periods?
I have an AutoHotkey (AHK) script that runs continuously in a loop. This script performs a sequence of actions and is of moderate complexity. The issue arises when the script has been running for approximately 4 hours. At that point, I receive the following error message:
Critical Error: Function recursion limit exceeded. The program is now unstable and will exit.
From what I understand, this error is related to recursion, but my script mainly relies on loops and repeated calls.
How can I adjust my script to avoid hitting this recursion limit during long execution periods?
I expected the script to run indefinitely without errors, as it primarily relies on loop. However, after around 4 hours of execution, it triggers the "Function recursion limit exceeded" error

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
